# Creating Registry

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to create an registry, but it give me following message.

Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\aspire' is denied

And following is my code.

```
protected void CreateRegistry()
    {
        dtStartDate = DateTime.Now;

        string strUser = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;

        RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
        //rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule("Administrator", RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
        rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(strUser, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));

        RegistryKey regDate = null;

        try
        {
            regDate = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey("Software\\aspire", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default, rs);

            if (regDate != null)
            {
                regDate.SetValue("Date", dtStartDate.ToString(strDateFormat));
                regDate.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("created");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

    }
```

when i am executing the same code in different system, the code runs correctly.
b'coz there isn't created any user on that system.
But now in this system i have created 2 user from control panel, and this is happening with me.
Both Systems are running on Windows 7.

PLease help

Thank you

Comment: You might have some good reasons for it but i am wondering why are you storing the values in registry, why not you use some configuration file?

Comment: Have you run this as admin? You don't provide a password in your code so if it's not being run as admin it won't allow a normal user to make these changes, hence the exception.

Comment: Could you please more specific?

Comment: @Deepak More specific how? Balusc has here provided you a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using windows 7, start run the application in administrator mode. if you are debugging from visual studio, start visual studio in administrator mode.

Comment: you want to say that i every user/client who is using my application has to execute the application "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: yes. if you are accessing the registry in windows 7 PC. You have to specify that in application manifest file.

Comment: Project -> Add New Item -> APplication Manifest File and replace the following line with the next one <requestedExecutionLevel  level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" /> with  <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />

Comment: Actually not "in the registry" but in the SOFTWARE RETISTRATION PART. THis is protected - installing software is an administrator / POWER USER scenario, NORMAL users are NOT allowed to install software in windows.

Comment: i made following changes in application's manifest file <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" /> and it's executing without displaying that message regarding permission. But when i am checking the registry, there is not any registry created. And if i am changing Registry.LocalMachine to Registry.CurrentUser it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Either a) run the application with elevated privileges or b) use HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead which is better practice anyway unless you really must install the software for all users.

If you want your application to request admin privileges by default, you need to add a manifest and add.

A prompt will pop up upon execution.

Comment: Do you mean `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`?

Comment: i tried to set the privileges as administrator programatically but it fail.

Comment: I'd suspect that an executable being able to elevate its own privileges would be extremely dangerous. See the answer below for how to start the application in administrator mode.

Comment: Please no "answer below". Answers reorder regularly based on votes.